# How to sort an alphanumeric column with different lengths in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have a column with values like below after **ordering** by it's column name **(equipment_no)** in **ASC** and was wondering how to sort it properly as shown in the next list.

```
SELECT equipment_no FROM fas_details WHERE equipment_no LIKE 'T%' ORDER BY equipment_no
```

Please do tell me your suggestions. Thank you.

**How mysql sorts**

```
T  - AG - 01
T  - AG - 02
T  - AG - 07
T  - AG - 08
T  - AG - 09
T  - AG - 10
T  - AG - 100
T  - AG - 101
T  - AG - 102
T  - AG - 103
T  - AG - 104
T  - AG - 11
T  - AG - 12
T  - AG - 13
T  - AG - 103
T  - AG - 104
TG - 10
TG - 100
TG - 99
```

**How I want it to be**

```
    T  - AG - 01
    T  - AG - 02
    T  - AG - 07
    T  - AG - 08
    T  - AG - 09
    T  - AG - 10
    T  - AG - 11
    T  - AG - 12
    T  - AG - 13
    T  - AG - 100
    T  - AG - 101
    T  - AG - 102
    T  - AG - 103
    T  - AG - 104
    TG - 10
    TG - 99
    TG - 100
```

Comment: Normalize your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want the last digits to be treated as a number.  The trick is handling the different number of hyphens in the name.  If there were just one hyphen, you could do:

```
order by substring_index(equipment_no, '-', 1),
         substring_index(equipment_no, '-', -1) + 0
```

In your case, this might work:

```
order by (case when equipment_no not like '%-%-%' 
               then substring_index(equipment_no, '-', 1)
               else substring_index(equipment_no, '-', 2)
          end),
         substring_index(equipment_no, '-', -1) + 0
```

This handles the 1 or 2 hyphen case, as in your example.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
SELECT 
equipment_no 
FROM fas_details 
WHERE equipment_no LIKE 'T%' 
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(equipment_no,SUBSTRING_INDEX(equipment_no ,'-',-1)+0,1), 
                 SUBSTRING_INDEX(equipment_no ,'-',-1)+0;
```

<kbd>[**Demonstration:**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/74084/4)</kbd>
 <sub>You can check demonstration here for four different sets of input</sub>

```
SET @str := 'T  - AG - 100';

SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(@str,'-',-1)+0 AS numberPart,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(@str,SUBSTRING_INDEX(@str,'-',-1)+0,1) AS textPart
```

**Output(for double hyphen):**

```
numberPart     textPart
100            T  - AG -
```

**Output(for single hyphen):**

`if equipment_no = 'TG - 100'`

```
numberPart      textPart
100                TG -
```

**Note:** It will work irrespective of the number of hyphens in your `equipment_no` column.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the part that you want to sort by using string functions. The example below will do it.

```
order by trim(SUBSTRING_INDEX(equipment_no, '-', -1))
```